# PhP shell_exec output convert to variable, and variable to image

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, shell-exec, openvz

In the days I started developing a VPS contol panel that communicates with the OpenVZ kernel using PhP commands.

I would like to display the status of the VPS, so it works so far.

```
<?php
$VMstatus = shell_exec("sudo vzctl status 17 | cut -d ' ' -f 5");
echo $VMstatus;
?>
```

It prints "running".

However, if the term "running"  word is  in the output, I would like to  display an image, but the following code does not display any images.

```
<?php
$VMstatus = shell_exec("sudo vzctl status 17 | cut -d ' ' -f 5");
echo $VMstatus;

if ($VMstatus == 'running') {
  echo "<img src='/assets/img/vps-running.png'>";
} else {
  echo "<img src='/assets/img/vps-down.png'>";
}
?>
```

What might be the problem?

Thank you in advance for your help! 
Have a nice day!

Comment: How does the html looks like in your browser? also do you see any 404's in your browsers devtool?

Comment: No. The path of the images is well defined.

Comment: Could it be that the images are corrupt? can you open them directly in your browser?

Comment: Also if you do `var_dump($VMstatus)` what do you get? it could have whitespaces.

Comment: Yes, the images work perfectly.

Comment: I get the following value: `string(8) "running "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell outputs whitespaces, you can remove those with the `trim` method. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
<?php
$VMstatus = trim(shell_exec("sudo vzctl status 17 | cut -d ' ' -f 5"));
echo $VMstatus;

if ($VMstatus == 'running') {
  echo "<img src='/assets/img/vps-running.png'>";
} else {
  echo "<img src='/assets/img/vps-down.png'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :)
It works! High five.